# Shuffle Mode with iPod... help ... Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ipod

I am trying to make it use the shuffle mode using

```
[self.musicPlayer setQueueWithQuery:shuffleMode];
```

But there is a warning saying makes pointer from integer without a cast. Now I know you can make a shuffle mode but I just cannot figure it out. Would I use it after setQueueWithQuery?

How would I use the shuffle mode with my app correctly? Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: How is `shuffleMode` defined?

Comment: MPMusicShuffleMode shuffleMode;
Then,
@property (nonatomic) MPMusicShuffleMode shuffleMode;
Then I synthesize it. I am just not sure how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

It's a property that's on the music player. And you set it with one of the constants that's already defined. e.g.:

```
[self.musicPlayer setShuffleMode:MPMusicShuffleModeSongs];
```